# How can I add new content to the contents of a variable and then replace that variable?

Tags: javascript

My title might not be perfectly worded and I'm sorry about that. Essentially, what I want done is this:

```
newc = 'wow'
    jQuery(".bleh").each(function(i){
       var bluh = *this changes with everytime this statement is run. lets call it x1, x2 and so on*
       var newc = bluh + newc
    });
```

Suppose the .each() function is only run twice (because there are two elements with the class "bleh"). I need `newc` to now be `'x2x1wow'` . 
As in the first time it ran it add the value if bluh (x1) to `'wow'` (initial value of newc)
Second time it adds the new value of bluh (x2) to `'x1wow'` (because that is the value of newc now) to return `newc = x2x1wow`

How would I achieve this?

Comment: `var bluh = 'x' + (i + 1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your variable outside the function, otherwise any changes will be lost when the function exits:

```
var newc = 'wow'
jQuery(".bleh").each(function(i)
{
   var bluh = *this changes with everytime this statement is run. lets call it x1, x2 and so on*
   newc = bluh + newc
});
```

The problem was in side the `each` callback your variable `newc` was declared as a local variable which will get resetted in every iteration. What you need is to modify the closure variable `newc` which is declared outside the loop, for that you can just remove the `var` in the callback function

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kePPh/)

Comment: What have you added/changed?!

Comment: @LeeTaylor `var` in the local variable

Comment: looks like all are blind

Comment: Why don't you explain your answer better?

Comment: I down-voted because you offered no explanation as to what you changed and why.  This answer isn't helpful to anyone but those who will forever ask on StackOverflow for every bump in the road they hit.  They can't learn from copy/paste code.

Comment: @Brad I was preparing a Fiddle to explain the case, which I posted now

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, but the fiddle doesn't "explain" anything.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Down-vote removed, now that you added an explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: @Brad I noramlly posts an answer then prepare a fiddle and then updated with some explanation...